# typescript type: define dictionary-like object type with a certain condition

Tags: typescript

How can we define the type that follows the rules below with typescript:

1. has certain keys and values(say: key1 of `srting` type and its value as `Date`)
2. may (or may not) have any kind of key-value pairs for the rest

image:

```js
{
 "key1": new Date(),
 "otherKey": "any value",
 ...
}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `[key: <type>]: <type>` to add custom amount to key-value pairs.

```js
const customType: {
    key: Date,
    [key:string]: any
  } = {
    key: new Date(),
    "string": "another value",
    "number": 10
    // [...]
  }
```

Comment: You might want to link to the documentation for [index signatures](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#index-signatures); note that the key type in an index signature (the type after the first colon) doesn't accept arbitrary keylike types; `string` (like you show here) is fine, but you can't write (e.g.,) `{[key: "a" | "b"]: number}`.